# List all available templates from CA certutil or certreq

Tags: certificate, certificate-authority, request

I need to request a certificate via command line I have investigated that *certreq* is the tool that can request the certificate.

I am used to the gui to request the certificate by selecting one of the available templates, but I need to do the same via command line.

Any ideas about how to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to display a list (in the command line) of certificate templates that are on offer by your friendly Active Directory Certificate Services CA, use `certutil -CATemplates`.

```
C:\Windows\system32>certutil -CATemplates
DirectoryEmailReplication: Directory Email Replication -- Auto-Enroll: Access is denied.
DomainControllerAuthentication: Domain Controller Authentication -- Auto-Enroll: Access is denied.
KerberosAuthentication: Kerberos Authentication -- Auto-Enroll: Access is denied.
EFSRecovery: EFS Recovery Agent -- Auto-Enroll: Access is denied.
EFS: Basic EFS -- Auto-Enroll: Access is denied.
DomainController: Domain Controller -- Auto-Enroll: Access is denied.
WebServer: Web Server -- Auto-Enroll: Access is denied.
Machine: Computer -- Auto-Enroll: Access is denied.
User: User -- Auto-Enroll: Access is denied.
SubCA: Subordinate Certification Authority -- Auto-Enroll: Access is denied.
Administrator: Administrator -- Auto-Enroll: Access is denied.
CertUtil: -CATemplates command completed successfully.
```

Bonus, it also tells you whether you currently have the right to enroll for each particular template.

To enroll in one of the certificate templates, use:

```
certreq -enroll -q WebServer
```

The `-q` parameter suppresses all interactive dialog boxes, making it a purely command-line-only experience.

Comment: how do I see details for each template? If I do "request new certificate" in mmc certificate snap-in there I can see it, but via command?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below command to list templates and their details:

```
certutil.exe -Template
```

Reference: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/certutil